# Using ZFS with Embedded Linux

Tags: linux, zfs

I'm running embedded Linux (Debian on ARM/X86_64). Since it is very much like a full OS, with some hardware differential and a different platform, you may consider it as a regular machine. So, this will be used in the robotics field where the computer will ALWAYS be hard reset by turning off power. It would disqualify me to use a UPS so I would need to make the system infallible.

I'm running some processor-intensive tasks, like OpenCV and OpenNI and OpenKinect. How do I use an uber-powerful filesystem, like ZFS to mirror the entire disk on the SSD for error correction? Does ZFS perform well in Linux? I'm still kinda a newbie in Linux so I don't understand it's internal workings.

My list of possible platforms are:
--Debian@RaspberryPi
--kUbuntu@ODROID-X2
--Ubuntu@PandaBoard
--Ubuntu@NUC-i3/5.

Also, how can I make sure the filesystem doesn't get damaged during reset? I need the computer to start in good time, A.K.A, <3 minutes for the competition.

I will probably be using a 32GB SSD, so I guess a 16GB partition mirrored 2x works or 12 @ 3x. I only need to get an OpenCV install working because the code will be downloaded from a SAMBA NFS automatically!

Thanks for your help and good luck ;)!

Answer (score 1):

ZFS is not suited for low memory systems. It do perform well on system with 4GB of RAM and more.

Comment: I think it should work as well as I need because the ssd will be around 32 GiB and the disk usage will be very minimal. This is in an embedded system where power faults will happen very often, purposefully. I need this system to be automatically able to recover from quite bad errors!

Comment: Just ZFS kernel module itself will eat significant part of memory... it you want ZFS forget Raspberry.

Comment: I was going to use an ODROID with 2 GiB of RAM. Also, my program will max out at 16MiB of usage, so all the RAM is basically free.